# json.dump not correctly saving json object

Tags: python, json, matplotlib

I have a function that plots data on a graph fetched from a website, that data is serialized in dictionaries and saved to a file named 'data.json'. The first dictionary is saved without any outstanding issues, however the second dictionary accurately saves all but the newest entry to the dictionary.

I've tried saving the data in different ways, all resulting in the same issue. I've narrowed it down to the save_data() function, after a considerable amount of time surfing the World Wide Web I am still at an impasse.

Here is the save_data function:

```py
def save_data():
    with open('./data.json', 'w') as data_file:
        json_object = {
            "sig_count_diff": {},
            "total_sig_count": {}
        }

        for key, value in total_signature_count.items():
            # print("For signature_count_difference: Key: " + str(key) + " Value: " + str(value))
            json_object["total_sig_count"].update({str(key): value})

        for key1, value1 in signature_count_difference.items():
            # print("For signature_count_difference: Key1: " + str(key1) + " Value1: " + str(value1))
            json_object["sig_count_diff"].update({str(key1): value1})


        print(json_object)
        json.dump(json_object, data_file)
```

Here is the animate function:

```py
def animate(i):
    raw_data = request.urlopen('https://petition.parliament.uk/petitions/241584.json').read()
    json_data = json.loads(raw_data)
    signature_count = json_data["data"]["attributes"]["signature_count"]
    last_updated = parser.parse(json_data["data"]["attributes"]["updated_at"])

    print("Last Updated: " + str(last_updated))
    ax1.clear()

    if len(total_signature_count) >= 1:
        last_sig_key = total_signature_count[list(total_signature_count.keys())[-1]]

        if last_sig_key == last_updated:
            return

        last_signature_count = total_signature_count[list(total_signature_count.keys())[-1]]
        difference = signature_count - last_signature_count

        if (difference > 0):
            print("Difference: " + str(difference) + " Last Signature Count: " + str(last_signature_count) + " Signature Count: " + str(signature_count))
        signature_count_difference.update({last_updated: difference})
        print(signature_count_difference)
        ax1.plot(signature_count_difference.keys(), signature_count_difference.values(), label="Unique Signatures")
        print(signature_count_difference)

    total_signature_count.update({last_updated: signature_count})
    save_data()
    ax1.plot(total_signature_count.keys(), total_signature_count.values(), label="Total Signature Count")
```

Here is a snippet of the console log:

```
Last Updated: 2019-03-23 20:49:37.538000+00:00
{datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 41, 38, 520000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 45, 38, 572000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 49, 37, 538000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0}
{datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 41, 38, 520000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 45, 38, 572000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 49, 37, 538000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0}
{'sig_count_diff': {'2019-03-23 20:41:38.520000+00:00': 0, '2019-03-23 20:45:38.572000+00:00': 0, '2019-03-23 20:49:37.538000+00:00': 0}, 'total_sig_count': {'2019-03-23 20:41:38.520000+00:00': 4648091, '2019-03-23 20:45:38.572000+00:00': 4651211, '2019-03-23 20:49:37.538000+00:00': 4654220}}
Last Updated: 2019-03-23 20:53:36.186000+00:00
=======> Difference: 3000 Last Signature Count: 4654220 Signature Count: 4657220
=== (signature_count_difference dict before it is saved)> {datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 41, 38, 520000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 45, 38, 572000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 49, 37, 538000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 53, 36, 186000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 3000}
{datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 41, 38, 520000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 45, 38, 572000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 49, 37, 538000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 53, 36, 186000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 3000}
=== (The JSON object supposedly saved)> {'sig_count_diff': {'2019-03-23 20:41:38.520000+00:00': 0, '2019-03-23 20:45:38.572000+00:00': 0, '2019-03-23 20:49:37.538000+00:00': 0, '2019-03-23 20:53:36.186000+00:00': 3000}, 'total_sig_count': {'2019-03-23 20:41:38.520000+00:00': 4648091, '2019-03-23 20:45:38.572000+00:00': 4651211, '2019-03-23 20:49:37.538000+00:00': 4654220, '2019-03-23 20:53:36.186000+00:00': 4657220}}
Last Updated: 2019-03-23 20:53:36.186000+00:00
=== (The next iteration of animate, difference. The difference value (3000) doesn't seem to have been saved) >{datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 41, 38, 520000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 45, 38, 572000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 49, 37, 538000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 53, 36, 186000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0}
{datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 41, 38, 520000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 45, 38, 572000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 49, 37, 538000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0, datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 23, 20, 53, 36, 186000, tzinfo=tzutc()): 0}
=== (JSON object of the next iteration, no entry with the value '3000' to be seen) > {'sig_count_diff': {'2019-03-23 20:41:38.520000+00:00': 0, '2019-03-23 20:45:38.572000+00:00': 0, '2019-03-23 20:49:37.538000+00:00': 0, '2019-03-23 20:53:36.186000+00:00': 0}, 'total_sig_count': {'2019-03-23 20:41:38.520000+00:00': 4648091, '2019-03-23 20:45:38.572000+00:00': 4651211, '2019-03-23 20:49:37.538000+00:00': 4654220, '2019-03-23 20:53:36.186000+00:00': 4657220}}
Last Updated: 2019-03-23 20:53:36.186000+00:00
```

I expected the result to be saved and the value to be plotted on the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries can only contain a given key once.  If you call `.update({key: val})` with a key that's already in the dict, it will replace the old value.

It looks like you're getting the date string key `'2019-03-23 20:53:36.186000+00:00'` more than once, and when you update the dict, you lose its original value of 3000.

Answer (score 0):

Ahah, I figured out the issue. A rather stupid blunder by myself. The difference is calculated by the last entry value and the current entry value, however they are both the same as I am attempting to calculate the difference after putting the current signature value into the same dictionary as the one I use to pull out the most recent value inserted into it.

I wasn't thinking logically last night!

Forgive the lack of linear thinking,
Thanks!